# PIL(pillow)で新しく作ったイメージだと、一部のメソッドが欠如する原因と、イメージ情報の永続化と復元の方法について

Tags: python, python3, pillow

`python`の画像処理系モジュールである`pillow`を使ってイメージから情報を取り出し、一旦`pickle`に保存して、
再度取り出した後、そのイメージをもとのイメージのように復元したい
と考えています。保存とロードで同じものを取り出すところまではできたんですが、
再度そこから元と同じイメージを作り出すのに、`new`メソッドを用いて、
それに読み込んだ情報を載せたいと思ったのですが、
`new`で作った`Image`クラスは、`fromarray`がないと言ってきます。
`asarray`で作った情報を保存しているので、`fromarray`出来るかなと思ったん
ですが、出来ませんでした。`Image.new()`で作ったオブジェクトは`Image`オブジェクトであり、`Image`オブジェクトはfromarrayメソッドを持っていると[公式](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/Image.html)には書いてあるのですが。
`print(type(tumps))

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

```
re_im.fromarray(tumps)

AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'fromarray'
```

これがサンプルコードです。

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
filename = 'any.png'
import pickle
im = Image.open(filename)
data = np.asarray(im.getdata())
f = open("test_file.dat","wb")

dumps = pickle.dump(data,f)

f = open("test_file.dat","rb")
tumps = pickle.load(f)
re_im = Image.new(im.mode, im.size)
re_im.fromarray(tumps)
re_im.show()


python3.6.3 
PIL.PILLOW_VERSION
Out[10]: '5.1.0'
```

Comment: 解決した場合は質問文への追記ではなく、「自己回答」として投稿しましょう。

Comment: @cubick 了解しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show()`のように`Image`クラス本体内で定義された関数（=メソッド）は、`re_im.show()`のように呼び出せますが、`fromarray()`のように`Image`クラス本体の外で定義された関数は、`re_im.fromarray()`のように呼び出せません。`Image.open()`と同様に`Image.fromarray()`で呼び出せば、少なくとも`AttributeError`は解消されます。

詳細はソースコードを確認して下さい。

https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/Image.py

Comment: 確かにエラーは発生しませんでした。しかしデータの復元は出来なかったので、これはまた別の問題となりますね。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 復元時に`im.getdata()`に対応する処理が無いように見えるので、`im.putdata()`あたりも必要かもしれませんね。

Answer (score 0):

(解決しました。）
永続化と復元の方は、Kohei TAMURAさんが解答いただいた後に追記し、それに対しての自己回答が見つかったのでここに追記します。

`np.asarray(im.getdata())`が絶対必要だとなぜか思ってたんですが、むしろ余計な処理でした。これを消去し、`data = np.array(im)`オープンしたイメージファイルをそのまま配列に載せるようにすればできました。

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
filename = 'any_data.png'
import pickle
im = Image.open(filename)

data = np.array(im)
f = open("test_file.dat","wb")

dumps = pickle.dump(data,f)

f = open("test_file.dat","rb")
tumps = pickle.load(f)

array = Image.fromarray(tumps)

array.show()
```